# Photo stream on iphone has old photos I deleted, but on desktop has recent ones I want to save

Tags: iphone, photo-stream

I'm trying to clear up space on my iphone , but Photo stream on iphone has about 4GB old photos I deleted, but on desktop has recent ones I want to save.

basically Photo Stream on my iphone shows pictures I've already deleted on my iphone clogging up my space, and I can't delete them on my iphone.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are looking for: do you need advice in deleting photos on your iPhone, are you wondering why your Photo Stream shows pictures you thought you've already deleted, are you looking for ways to load photos from your computer (desktop) into your phone, or something else altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You can try turning off Photo Stream on your iPhone, and turning it back on after a few minutes, to see if it purges the old photos in the process.